# I'm trying to run a pyautogui program in background on a raspberry pi 4

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, pyautogui, raspberry-pi4

I am using a pyautogui to automate stuff with my raspberry pi 4 and I wanted to run the python program as soon as I boot in my raspberry pi

The code that I used is: `sudo nohup python3 main.py &`

All my other programs who doesnt have the **pyautogui package** of python execute properly but this doesn't!

I know the error is in pyautogui package and I want that package for my project

The error that arises is:

```
File "./server.py", line 14, in <module>
    import pyautogui as pya
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 249, in <module>
    import mouseinfo
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/mouseinfo/__init__.py", line 223, in <module>
    _display = Display(os.environ['DISPLAY'])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 678, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'DISPLAY'
INFO:     Stopping reloader process [1006]
```

If I run the same command that is: `sudo nohup python3 main.py &` after loggin in and opening a terminal and then entering this command then this works exactly as expected.

I think that the error is probably due to the display not initialised

My python program contains this code

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.moveTo(0,100)
```

> *And please note that the above program is just for demonstration.. if this works then I am going to implement other awesome stuffs*